# Esp8266 "parseObject() failed" in serial monitor. How to Resolve?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-c++

I am getting this error "parseObject() failed" while connecting it to my data base.
my host is "iot.speedster.in"
php version is 5.2
I have tried it with different buffer size 
-200
-300
-400
but still i got the error.
I also tried changing php versions but still didn't resolved.
The arduino code is uploading fine in my board. I have also uploaded "db-config" & "db-update" file.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "smnet";
const char* password = "123456786";
const char* host = "iot.speedster.in"; //replace it with your webhost url
String url;
int count = 0;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(100);
    pinMode(D1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(D2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(D3, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(D1, 0);
    digitalWrite(D2, 0);
    digitalWrite(D3, 0);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.print("Netmask: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.subnetMask());
    Serial.print("Gateway: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.gatewayIP());
    digitalWrite(D1, 1);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(D1, 0);
    delay(500);
}

void loop()
{

    Serial.print("connecting to ");
    Serial.println(host);

    WiFiClient client;
    const int httpPort = 80;
    if (!client.connect(host, httpPort))
    {
        Serial.println("connection failed");
        return;
    }

    if (count == 0)
    {
        url = "/api/led/read_all.php?id=1";
        count = count + 1;
        Serial.println("Here1");
    }
    else if (count == 1)
    {
        url = "/api/led/read_all.php?id=2";
        count = count + 1;
        Serial.println("Here2");
    }
    else if (count == 2)
    {
        url = "/api/led/read_all.php?id=3";
        count = count + 1;
        Serial.println("Here3");
    }
    Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
    Serial.println(url);

    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: " + host
            + "\r\n" + "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
    delay(500);
    String section = "header";
    while (client.available())
    {
        String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
        //Serial.print(line);
        // we’ll parse the HTML body here
        if (section == "header")
        { // headers..

            if (line == "\n")
            { // skips the empty space at the beginning 
                section = "json";
            }
        }
        else if (section == "json")
        { // print the good stuff
            section = "ignore";
            String result = line.substring(1);

            // Parse JSON
            int size = result.length() + 1;
            char json[size];
            result.toCharArray(json, size);
            StaticJsonBuffer < 200 > jsonBuffer;
            JsonObject& json_parsed = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);
            if (!json_parsed.success())
            {
                Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
                return;
            }
            String led = json_parsed["led"][0]["status"];

            if (count == 1)
            {
                if (led == "on")
                {
                    digitalWrite(D1, 1);
                    delay(100);
                    Serial.println("D1 is On..!");
                }
                else if (led == "off")
                {
                    digitalWrite(D1, 0);
                    delay(100);
                    Serial.println("D1 is Off..!");
                }
            }
            else if (count == 2)
            {
                if (led == "on")
                {
                    digitalWrite(D2, 1);
                    Serial.println("D2 is On..!");
                }
                else if (led == "off")
                {
                    digitalWrite(D2, 0);
                    Serial.println("D2 is Off..!");
                }
            }
            else if (count == 3)
            {
                if (led == "on")
                {
                    digitalWrite(D3, 1);
                    Serial.println("D3 is On..!");
                }
                else if (led == "off")
                {
                    digitalWrite(D3, 0);
                    Serial.println("D3 is Off..!");
                }
                count = 0;
            }

            if (count == 3)
                count = 0;

        }
    }
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("closing connection");
    delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your   `String result = line.substring(1);` is coming with a correct JSON data?

Comment: I think Yes, It is coming